# how can I combine a group statemant with a calculation?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I would like to normalize a column. (= divide by sum())
I tried this:

```
select @w:=sum(lastprice), lastprice/@w 
from  aktien 
GROUP BY TradeDate;
```

but get always NULL for the 2nd select part.
How can this be done ?
Walter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting `NULL` because MySQL does not guarantee the order in which user defined variables will be evaluated inside a `SELECT` clause. Also, what you are trying to achieve is not valid aggregation; you will need to first calculate the `SUM()` in a separate sub-query (Derived Table), and then join it back to compute the normalized values:

```
SELECT a.TradeDate, 
       a.lastprice, 
       a.lastprice/b.sum_last_price AS normalized_last_price 
FROM aktien AS a 
JOIN (SELECT TradeDate, SUM(lastprice) AS sum_last_price 
      FROM aktien 
      GROUP BY TradeDate) b ON b.TradeDate = a.TradeDate
```

Comment: THANKs a lot - for opening my eyes.